# SFMC authentication, does the offline token work for all accounts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, authentication

we need your help if possible.

We have been using the offline token successfully to authenticate & refresh our token for our Hub Exchange app. This allows us to access the client's account when they are offline.

It works for about 50 accounts with no issue, but it does seem to break with one very large client account e.g. using the offline token does not refresh our access.

Is it possible that the offline token is not allowed from certain client accounts for security reasons?

Thanks a lot,
Alex